# React: how to set focus on last input after adding it?

Tags: reactjs

can you please help me figure out how to set focus on last input after adding it by click on button?

```js
function InputList() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const add = useCallback(() => setItems([...items, {id: uniqId()}]), [items]);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => <input key={item.id}/>)}
      <button onClick={add} type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You have to use `useRef` to create a reference and save in the current the last input, after that you can use focus in an effect to set it. If you could provide a Sandbox I could help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easiest way is to pass the same `ref` to all the `input`s:

```
const refToLast = React.createRef();
useEffect(() => {
  refToLast.current.focus();
});
...
      {items.map(item => <input ref={refToLast} key={item.id}/>)}
...
```

But we may found that we setting focus to last input on each re-rendering(even when we type some value). So we may add condition to set focus only when `items.length` is changed:

```
useEffect(() => {
  refToLast.current.focus();
}, [items.length]);
```

But that would also run when we *remove* entry not adding them. Not sure if that's desired.

[upd] to skip setting focus on initial rendering we can add additional flag:

```
const doSetAutoFocus = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  refToLast.current.focus();
}, [items.length, doSetAutoFocus]);

const onAddClicked = useCallback(() => {
  add();
  doSetAutoFocus.current = true;
}, [add])
```

Comment: Thank you, nice idea with `items.length` but I want focus last input only after click on "add" button, not on first render

Comment: to make it work properly I made few changes
```lang-js
const lastInput = useRef(null);
const focus = useRef(false);

const add = useCallback(() => {
  focus.current = true;
  setItems(...);
}, [items]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!lastInput.current || !focus.current) return;

  lastInput.current.focus();
  focus.current = false;
}, [list.length]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `autoFocus` property and `index` (second argument of map) ,

```
{items.map((item,i) => <input key={item.id} autoFocus={i === items.length - 1 ? true : false}/>)}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ffs5ks)

Comment: Thank you, but it has same problem as with previous - last input will be focused on every render, but I need only after click on "add" button

Comment: Check the demo. I think the last input is getting focused only after button click.